# Complex input for Compile makes it slow

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, complex

I asked a question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71490/making-table-of-matrix-product-and-efficiency/71505#71505) and then tried to use `Compile` for the solution to gain even more speed. Inside `Compile` there is a loop which calculate matrix multiplications of this type :

```
Transpose[vector].matrix.vector;
```

the `matrix` is a list of matrices.

```
<< Developer`
n = 24;
m = 1000;

matrix = ToPackedArray@Transpose[Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}]];
(*a tensor*)

vector = N[{IdentityMatrix[n][[1]]}\[Transpose]];
```

and,

```
funComplex = Compile[{{mymatrix, _Real, 3}, {myvector, _Complex, 2}, {number, _Integer}}, Do[Flatten[#1\[ConjugateTranspose].mymatrix.#1 &[myvector]], {ite, 1, number}]]
```

In the `Compile` I assumed `myvector` could be `Complex`. In the below, I assume `myvector` is `Real`:

```
funReal = Compile[{{mymatrix, _Real, 3}, {myvector, _Real, 2}, {number, _Integer}}, Do[Flatten[#1\[ConjugateTranspose].mymatrix.#1 &[myvector]], {ite, 1, number}]]
```

`number` is the number of iteration inside `Do`.

```
funComplex[matrix, vector, 1000] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{2.970004, Null}*)

funReal[matrix, vector, 1000] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.120000, Null}*)
```

As you see if I use `Complex` inside `Compile` it gets 25 times more slow.
If inside `Compile` for `funComplex` I use `Complex` type for `mymatrix` then `funComplex` becomes considerably faster but not as fast as `funReal`:

```
funComplex2 = Compile[{{mymatrix, _Complex, 3}, {myvector, _Complex, 2}, {number, _Integer}}, Do[Flatten[#1\[ConjugateTranspose].mymatrix.#1 &[myvector]], {ite, 1, number}]]

funComplex2[matrix, vector, 1000] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.600001, Null}*)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked whether your function compiled successfully in all details with `CompilePrint`?

Comment: I used 

<< CompiledFunctionTools`
On[Compile::noinfo]

To see if there is any error. I will use `CompilePrint`.

Comment: I have no idea what the output of `CompilePrint` means. I can't see any error in the output.

Comment: Can you tell me what happens if you use [the following definition of `funComplex`](http://hastebin.com/ijuhapuper.pas)? I get only very small differences between real and complex now. And can you verify that this code is equivalent to what you want?

Comment: The code you mentioned is what I want, but its performance is the same as `funComplex2` is this question, and it is less than the performance of `funReal`.

Comment: When I see this right, then you can split your final calculation into the real and imaginary part easily. That means, you can the real and imaginary part separately in two `funReal` calls and add the matrices together. Have you considered this? It would mean that you need 2x the time of a `funReal` call.

Comment: I will work on your suggestion today to see if that works.
Aside from my original problem, I would like to know what is the reason of this behavior.